# Inserting data via C# is inaccessible when queried

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

I am having a very annoying issue with a program I am currently making. In the program a teacher with admin status can add a user to a students_tbl Table in an SQL database by adding in relevant information. The following code adds a Student to the student_tbl in C#.

```
string studentAdd = "Insert Into student_tbl(Forename, Surname, SchlYear, InOrOut, Block1, Block2, Block3, Block4, Pword) Values (@forename, @surname, '" + SchlYear + "', '" + inOrOut + "' , '" + Blocks[0] + "', '" + Blocks[1] + "', '" + Blocks[2] + "', '" + Blocks[3] + "', @password)";
SqlCommand studentAddCommand = new SqlCommand(studentAdd, con);
studentAddCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@forename", Forename));
studentAddCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@surname", Surname));
studentAddCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", hashedPassword));
studentAddCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Student Added Successfully");
con.Close();
```

The variables added in to the table come from results and are simply just names, integers and bools, nothing complex.

The issue I am having is that this data is inaccessible when trying to log in as a student added via this system. If a user is added manually through SSMS then it works fine. Is this something ridiculously basic I am missing, as if I was to add a user ie. 'Joe Bloggs', and search

```
Select UserID from student_tbl Where Forename = 'Joe'
```

It simply finds nothing.
Does anybody have any glaring issues I am missing, or not declaring etc? I am able to provide any more information if it could lead to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the forename column has the value 'Joe' and not 'Joe Bloggs' ?

Comment: can you do like rather than =

Comment: Yes, as Joe would come from a Forename Text box inserted by a user, as would the Surname, which is totally separate from eachother

Comment: Why are you mixing the right method (parameters) and the wrong method (concatenate strings)?

Comment: `Where Forename like '%Joe%' or Forename is null`, just check for null to see if forename is not getting a value

Comment: Are you trimming the values before committing? Is the a postfix space or something?

Comment: You don't check the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` to make sure your command executed correctly, you just assume it worked. The return value is the number of rows affected, in your case `1`. Run this code again and inspect the value returned, what is it?

Comment: So having added through a totally new user 'Test Test', using the "like '%Test%'" finally works, is there any reason for it doing this, and why I must go the long way around so as to access the data I am looking for?

Comment: what type is `hashedPassword`? is there a try...catch around ignoring exceptions? is there an open transaction on the connection, which is rolled back later? are you using `nchar` not `nvarchar` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Jeroen van Langen  comment, try to trim values:

```
studentAddCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@forename", Forename.Trim()));
studentAddCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@surname", Surname.Trim()));
```

Comment: Thanks for @Jeroen van Langen  :)